# Microsoft Visual Studio finds errors with all of my CUDA device-side functions

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cuda

I was wondering if anyone can help with this error I'm getting in Cuda code. I want to define the function but it's saying that this declaration has no storage class or type specifier. Anyone know what should I do? [This](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0BgiMZ1gMsyekNnb3FRU1lBWkU) is a link to the screenshot of the error.

Comment: the red underline is just an intellisense incompatibility with CUDA syntax.  If you want more explanation, you could google "cuda red underline"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RobertCrovella explains, this is just your IDE not being aware of CUDA keywords when parsing your source.

Something you could do is make your parser find a

```
#define __device__
```

line, which would make it stop complaining. The problem is, you want the CUDA compiler not to hit this `#define`. So you can put it within an `#ifdef`, like so:

```
#ifdef __CUDACC__
#define __device__
#endif
```

which does the trick.

Of course, this only handles one keyword, `__device__`. You would need to have similar definitions for all CUDA keywords, as well as types and functions which are implicitly defined.